# Azure AD SAML Inconsistency related to MFA Prompting

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, multi-factor-authentication

I have two enterprise apps (well I have hundreds but for this we will say two). Both leverage Windows Auth via Kerberos/SPN.

IF I am already logged onto portal.office.com and go to app [A] then I see the redirection to login.microsoftonline.com and then back to app [A] logged in without the need for MFA (presumably because I did it when logging into portal.office.com).

However, again already logged into portal.office.com and goto app [B] then I get redirected to login.microsoftonline.com, it knows who I am, but it forces MFA prompting.

The account in question is MFA Disabled on the MFA User screen, and both apps are covered by a single conditional access policy that says "all apps, all users, require MFA".

Looking in the Azure AD Sign-On logs for App A, the seamless logon shows this:

> MFA Result: MFA requirement satisfied by claim in the token

Where App B doesn't seem to respect the token and or is not being presented by it.

Does anyone know why two roughly identical enterprise apps would have this different behavior? 
Any troubleshooting steps I might be able to take?

I have opened three cases so far, never get past level 1 before I give up. Fiddler traces haven't really shown me anything.

Any advice would be greatly welcomed.

Answer (score 1):

This sometimes happens if a user is using Windows 10. You may need to install an update to avoid the MFA prompts.

This can also happen if any form of MFA is required on-premises. https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/cloudpfe/2017/03/15/multiple-mfa-prompts-connecting-to-office-365/

Another option to avoid multiple MFA prompts is to remember MFA for trusted devices.